# How to have a link in label of a form field

Tags: django

I want to have a checkbox for terms and conditions, label of which should contain a link to a page with, well, terms and conditions.

The following field will have the label with the tags escaped.

```
BooleanField(label="I agree to <a href='terms-conditions.html'>terms&conditions</a>")
```

Comment: it looks like it is impossible to do it withing django framework's constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how django works, but if the label in the above code creates a:

```
<label>I agree to terms&conditions</label>
```

element then this is NOT the way to do this.

The label element inherently selects the associated field by default, so you'd be mixing 2 click actions (one that checks, and another that opens a window)

I would just add your label, and an a:href beside it.

```
<label>I agree to terms&conditions</label> (<a href="terms-conditions.html">terms&conditions</a>)
```

Answer (score 45):

Import django's mark_safe from utils.safestring as explained at http://www.kelvinism.com/howtos/using-html-django-form-label/

From the link:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import forms

class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(), 
                           max_length=15, 
                           label=mark_safe('Your Name (<a href="/questions/whyname/" target="_blank">why</a>?)'))
```

Comment: If instead of hardcoding the URL you want to use `reverse`, then you can't use it at field definition. You must set the label value from inside the Form constructor after calling `super`.

Comment: Or use reverse_lazy which is meant for such cases!

Answer (score 11):

Here is the correct link to [the Django documentation on the subject of iteration over the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).

What you want is:

```
<form method="post">
{% for field in form %}
    <p>
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        {% if field.name == "toc" %}
          <a href="{% url terms %}">Terms and Conditions</a>
        {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: The url name should be in quotes.
`<a href="{% url 'terms' %}">Terms and Conditions</a>`

Answer (score 9):

If do not wish to hardcode the URL, you could set the field's label from the constructor:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length='255', label=_('Name'))
    forms.BooleanField(label=_("Terms and Conditions"), required=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        terms_and_conditions = reverse_lazy("terms_and_conditions")
        self.fields['read_terms'].label = mark_safe(_("I have read and agree with the "
                                                      "<a href='%s'>Terms and Conditions</a>")) % (terms_and_conditions)
```

Comment: Actually the formatting should be placed in `mark_safe` like: `mark_safe(_("I have read and agree with the <a href='%s'>Terms and Conditions</a>") % (terms_and_conditions,))`

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess - you're using `django_registration` - I see I'm not the only person who had this problem:)

As [scunliffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144/scunliffe) said markup is best left out of the label tag - here is a short template snippet to do what you want without resorting to writing the whole thing out in HTML:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {% ifequal field.name 'tos' %}
        <a href="/terms/">I have read and agreed to the Terms of Service</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also think that to hardcode link in label isn't a good variant. so it'll be better to use `render_to_string` from `django.template.loader`. Also we need to think about laziness like for i18n. `keep_lazy_text` and `lazystr` fits our requirements for it.  So the result it:

*forms.py*

```py
from django.utils.functional import keep_lazy_text, lazystr
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

lazy_render_to_string = keep_lazy_text(render_to_string)


def lazy_render(template_name):
    """
    Keep laziness for rendering to string from template
    """
    return lazy_render_to_string(lazystr(template_name))


class ExtendedSignupForm(SignupForm):

    accept_term_of_use = forms.BooleanField(
        label=lazy_render('common/accept_term_of_use_label.html'),
        required=True
    )

    field_order = [
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'accept_term_of_use'
    ]
```

*common/accept_term_of_use_label.html*

```html
Accept <a href="{% url "term_of_use" %}" target="_blank">Term Of Use</a> and <a href="privacy_statement" target="_blank">Privacy Statement</a>.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old but I have found a solution

forms.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.functional import lazy

privacy = forms.BooleanField(label = lazy(lambda: _("Privacy <a href='%s' a>policy</a>" % reverse('privacy'))))
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned, how to call label in html page? Like normally `wtforms` label called using `{{ form.field.label(class="abc") }}`. How this kind of label will be called in html page?

Comment: for call just the privacy label `{{ name_form.privacy}}` but you can just call the entire form `{{ form_name}}` and django automatically render all field of the form.